# module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies for BViewBinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I am trying to enable View Binding on a project and I have this error:

> Cannot access 'no_name_in_PSI_3d19d79d_1ba9_4cd0_b7f5_b46aa3cd5d40'
> which is a supertype of
> 'com.kevinabrioux.ping.databinding.ActivityStartingBinding'. Check
> your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

This is where my error appear:

[image]

I have activate viewbinding in my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kevinabrioux.ping"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was happening because I had pasted in the `<layout>` tag in my XML and I wasn't using databinding.

Removing the `<layout>` tag fixed the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Remove this layout tag and make LinearLayout the root -->
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".viewPresenter.webBrowser.WebBrowserFragment">
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: But, If remove the layout tag, then how we will use the data binding?

Comment: @Pushpendra I am not using data binding and I think the OP isn't either. In case you are, I guess you will need to add data biding dependencies?

Comment: If We add the dependencies then problem is coming as mention above. After removing above layout. Then it is working fine. But giving errors for data binding. Specially in gradle version 7.0.1.

Comment: @Pushpendra I have never worked with data binding before, but maybe [this repo](https://github.com/android/databinding-samples) can help you. Please also confirm if Android supports gradle version 7.0.1. Android didn't use to work with latest versions of gradle, at least a few years back.

Comment: Okay thank you @Sufian for your quick response. As you shared the Above Repo. Yes It is working fine in gradle version 4.2.1. But As I upgraded it to the latest version. It stopped working again. I am not sure, But I think android studio need to look into it!

Comment: @Pushpendra 4.2.1 must be gradle plugin version. The gradle plugin versions are set in the build.gradle file, whereas the grade versions are set in the [gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties](https://github.com/android/databinding-samples/blob/main/BasicSample/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties). This is something which I used to have confusion about.

Comment: Hmm okay no problem, Till next clarification by the Android Studio on it. I will use only gradle 4.2.0